# nginx keeps passing the same http_cookie to uwsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have a small python app running via uwsgi with requests served by nginx.

I'm printing the environment variables... and it looks like after a couple of ok requests, nginx is sending the same HTTP_COOKIE param for unrelated requests:

For example:

> {'UWSGI_CHDIR': '/ebs/py', 'HTTP_COOKIE':
>   'ge_t_c=4fcee8450c3bee709800920c', 'UWSGI_SCRIPT': 'server',
>   'uwsgi.version': '1.1.2', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'PATH_INFO':
>   '/redirect/ebebaf3b-475a-4010-9a72-96eeff797f1e', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL':
>   'HTTP/1.1', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'x-wsgiorg.fdevent.readable':
>   , 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
>   'uwsgi.ready_fd': None, 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)', 'HTTP_CONNECTION':
>   'close', 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.facebook.com/', 'SERVER_NAME':
>   'pixel.domain.com', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.load.bal.ip',
>   'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'wsgi.multiprocess':
>   True, 'uwsgi.node': 'py.domain.com', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT':
>   '/etc/nginx/html', 'UWSGI_PYHOME': '/ebs/py', 'uwsgi.core': 127,
>   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http', 'x-wsgiorg.fdevent.writable':
>   , 'wsgi.input':
>   ,
>   'HTTP_HOST': 'track.domain.com', 'wsgi.multithread': False,
>   'REQUEST_URI': '/redirect/ebebaf3b-475a-4010-9a72-96eeff797f1e',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
>   'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'x-wsgiorg.fdevent.timeout': None,
>   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '10.load.bal.ip', 'wsgi.errors': , 'REMOTE_PORT': '36462',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US', 'wsgi.run_once': False,
>   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT': '80', 'CONTENT_TYPE': '',
>   'wsgi.file_wrapper': ,
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate'}

and

> {'UWSGI_CHDIR': '/ebs/py', 'HTTP_COOKIE':
>   'ge_t_c=4fcee8450c3bee709800920c', 'UWSGI_SCRIPT': 'server',
>   'uwsgi.version': '1.1.2', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'PATH_INFO':
>   '/redirect/2391e658-95ef-4300-80f5-83dbb1a0e526', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL':
>   'HTTP/1.1', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'x-wsgiorg.fdevent.readable':
>   , 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '',
>   'uwsgi.ready_fd': None, 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS
>   5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3', 'HTTP_CONNECTION':
>   'close', 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.facebook.com/', 'SERVER_NAME':
>   'pixel.domain.com', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.load.balancer.ip',
>   'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'wsgi.multiprocess':
>   True, 'uwsgi.node': 'py.domain.com', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT':
>   '/etc/nginx/html', 'UWSGI_PYHOME': '/ebs/py', 'uwsgi.core': 127,
>   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'http', 'x-wsgiorg.fdevent.writable':
>   , 'wsgi.input':
>   ,
>   'HTTP_HOST': 'fire.domain.com', 'wsgi.multithread': False,
>   'REQUEST_URI': '/redirect/2391e658-95ef-4300-80f5-83dbb1a0e526',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT':
>   'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
>   'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'x-wsgiorg.fdevent.timeout': None,
>   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '10.load.bal.ip', 'wsgi.errors': , 'REMOTE_PORT': '39498',
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-us', 'wsgi.run_once': False,
>   'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT': '80', 'CONTENT_TYPE': '',
>   'wsgi.file_wrapper': ,
>   'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate'}

These are 2 distinct clients. I opened an incognito session, confirmed that no cookie was sent in the headers, and the uwsgi log shows that it received the same HTTP_COOKIE.

How can I make sure that nginx only passes the proper information for the current request, without regard to other requests?

Comment: What version of uwsgi? Are you using asycn? I was experiencing the same problem, and it was a uwsgi bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598935/uwsgi-resends-headers-in-async-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...

I had to add this line to uwsgi_params in /etc/nginx/

uwsgi_param HTTP_COOKIE     $http_cookie;

Without it, the HTTP_COOKIE variable could not be trusted in uwsgi/python app.