# uwsgi resends headers in async mode

Tags: python, asynchronous, uwsgi

It seems uwsgi remembers headers from a previous request in async mode!

I deployed a very simple application with uwsgi:
`def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    environ_repr = '\n'.join(sorted(key.ljust(30) + ' = ' + repr(value) for key, value in environ.items()))
    return [environ_repr]`
and ran it with:
`uwsgi --module index -s 0.0.0.0:8000 -p 1 --async 5`
Steps to regenerate the problem:

- Visit 127.0.0.1:8000 with header "Key: Value", there is `HTTP_KEY` entry in `environment`, OK.
- Now, visit 127.0.0.1:8000 without that header, but `HTTP_KEY` entry still is present `environment`, oopch!

Note: Same thing happens with other headers like `Cookie`!

(Tested with uwsgi 1.0, 1.2.4 and 1.3-dev, and python 2.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in uwsgi and fixed in:

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/commit/e393f36f0adbdb49e4a84098865bb6e3c01785e4